# Identifying the limit in the function

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives

[image]

We see in the third part part that limit of 2$\theta$ is between -$\frac{\pi}{2}$ and -$\pi$ which become $-\frac{\pi}{2}<\pi + 2\theta<0$.

How do we know that $2\theta$ became $\pi + 2\theta$ with its limit from -$\frac{\pi}{2}$ and -$\pi$ to $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $0$?

Please answer the question with respect to range of x given in third part of the question.
[image]

In this image why we don't use 
$\pi + 3\theta$ instead of $-\pi - 3\theta$.

Comment: [Please use MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: That's just a printing mistake..

Comment: @WinVineeth It isn't a printing mistake as there are many question in the book which is solved similarly.

Comment: @pcforgeek $-\pi<2\theta<-$$\pi\over 2$ cannot imply $-$$\pi\over 2$$<\pi+2\theta<0$

Answer (score 0):

By trigonometric identity

$$\mp\sin x=\sin\pi\cos x\pm\sin x\cos\pi=\sin(x\pm\pi)$$

Thus, $\;\sin(2\theta+\pi)=-\sin\theta\;$ , and from here that minus sign there.

Acclaration to comment:

$$-\pi<\theta<-\frac\pi2\stackrel{\cdot2}\implies-2\pi<2\theta<-\pi\stackrel{+\pi}\implies -\pi<\pi+2\theta<0$$

Comment: Please tell how the limit changes to -$\frac{\pi}{2}$ and -$\pi$ to $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $0$ as $\theta$ changes to $\pi + 2\theta$?

Comment: @pcforgeek Read what I added to answer.

Comment: What about the doubt related to the second image?

Comment: Do the same as above

Comment: See the written part at the lower end of the image.